# how to check if the user sent json web token or not?

Tags: javascript, express

i am pretty new to express and struggling with this error for quite some time.

```
    
    const token=req.header("jwt")
    console.log(token)
    if(!token ){
        return res.json('no jwt')
        console.log('nojwt')
    }
    try{

    const logged_in=verify(token,'j_token')
        console.log(logged_in)
    if(logged_in){
        
        req.user=logged_in
        next();
        
    }}catch{err=>console.log(err)}
    
}
```

iam not getting response of 'no jwt' even when iam not sending the jwt

Comment: switch the order of the two lines in the if statement ... nothing runs after a `return`

Comment: @JaromandaX tried it still no message.also not getting any response

Comment: are you sure `req.header` is a **function**?

Comment: @JaromandaX if iam sending the valid token iam getting the correct response.so iam pretty sure req.header works

Comment: good point - not sure why the `console.log('nojwt')` doesn't work if you put it above `return res.json('no jwt')` - what does `console.log(typeof token)` output

Answer (score 0):

```
    console.log('All Headers =',req.headers);

    let token=req.headers['jwt'];
    console.log('token =',token);

    if(token==null || token==undefined || token==''){
      console.log('No Token');
      return res.json({status:"error", message :"no jwt token"});
    }else{
       console.log('Token is there');
    }
```

Comment: it prints token as null but 'no Token' is not logged

Comment: tried it but still not getting logged.i tried token=='null' and it worked any idea?

Comment: @akhilsai - it must be the way you're sending the token if a null token results in the string `"null"`

Comment: iam  using axios.
```axios.post('http://localhost:3001/comments/',comment,{
            headers:{
                jwt:sessionStorage.getItem("jwt")
            }```